# howto view with curl meta data (search engine rich snippet)?

Tags: curl, metadata, google-search, search-engines, snippets

When I search for "slashdot", Google present me this rich snippet:

[image]

How to view the meta data definition with curl? For example: `curl https://slashdot.org/metadata.rdf`. Is there some standard location on web root?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a Google rich snippet.

Google calls them [**sitelinks**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21238921/1591669), and (contrary to rich snippets) authors can’t do anything to get these. So you can’t possibly find anything in the site’s markup.

If it *were* a rich snippet, you wouldn’t find the relevant data in a metadata file (Google doesn’t support it). Instead, you would find markup on the relevant page(s). You would have to look for structured data in certain syntaxes ([JSON-LD](https://www.w3.org/TR/json-ld/), [Microdata](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/microdata.html), [RDFa](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-rdfa/)), making use of a certain vocabulary ([Schema.org](http://schema.org/)). So you would have to `curl` the HTML documents, and use a JSON-LD, a Microdata, and a RDFa parser to extract any structured data.